# Чистая установка El Capitan на MacBook Pro: Требуется диск с точкой подключения

Tags: macos

Заменил на MacBook Pro 2011 винчестер (полетел старый), установил SSD.
Сделал загрузочную флешку с El Capintan, после перезагрузки нажал Option и поехали.
Загрузка с флешки.
Дисковая утилита. Стер с пустого диска всё, в журналируемом формате как дисковая утилита и предложила.
Начал установку. Установщик показывал 13 мин до окончания на протяжении получаса, а потом выдал сообщение: Требуется диск с точкой подключения.
Что за диск, что за точка подключения?
Делал проверку диска

```
$diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk0s2
много текста
... ok
```

Пытался сделать установку с интернета (загружался Lion), так же стирал диск (иначе не видел). Но всё равно выдавал ошибку после долгого ожидания, что установка не удалась.

[image: Требуется диск с точкой подключения]

Подскажите, плз, что делать?

Answer (score 2):

В моём случае оказалось более, чем прозаично. Взял у друга старый macBook 2009, подключил новый ssd как флешку на 120 ГБ и установил из скачанного дистрибутива El Capitan на внеший диск систему.
Вернул винт на место и всё!!!
Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся... :)